# Comparison of rolap and molap in the tubular or multidimensional environment is better?

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssas, olap

I want to write a comparison article on ROLAP and MOLAP, and I have installed SSAS. During the installation process, there was a Tabular section and a Multidimensional section that I needed to choose from. As far as I knew, Tabular is specifically for ROLAP, and Multidimensional is tailored for MOLAP. However, it seems that both environments support both ROLAP and MOLAP. Which option is better, and if, for instance, your choice is Multidimensional, could you explain how ROLAP works within it? Additionally, what dataset or database would you recommend for analyzing and comparing both methods? Finally, if the dataset is two-dimensional or relational, should it be transformed in ssis into a data cube for MOLAP to function? Is such a conversion possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.